# Any experience with drop in website User Feedback services like Usersnap?

Tags: user-feedback, usersnap

We've used the JIRA Issue Collection plugin to handle our websites user feedback form in the past, but would like to give users more capabilities like screenshots and annotations.  Usersnap looks interesting, but I can't find much information on it beyond what is on their site.

Has anyone else used it or a similar library or service?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

[Usersnap](https://usersnap.com) offers a [JIRA](https://usersnap.com/jira) integration ([Installation Docs](https://usersnap.com/doc/connect/jira)), so it should be a drop in replacement for the JIRA Issue Collection plugin.
Moreover, your users don't need to install anything, it's fully browser based.

Having a screenshot from your customer is often a live saver - imagine "The button is too small" bug reports without knowing which exact button.

Comment: Thanks Gregor.  We've been testing it out and it works really great.  I was just wondering if the user community has any feedback, since you are a founder.